# No records were selected - S_P00_07000134 SAP ABAP

Tags: abap

Getting 'no records were selected' when I execute T-code S_P00_07000134 to view withholding tax report.

Looking forward to your guidance if there are some configurations need to be done in order to fix the error statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide us with your entered data in the selection screen?
You can also take a look here https://answers.sap.com/questions/7522494/no-records-were-selected---sp0007000134.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is a help site about programming questions. You may ask your question in Web sites like https://superuser.com or https://scn.sap.com

Comment: Did you change that program in any way that could affect the results? If yes, please show us those changes. If no, then this isn't a question about programming. It's a question about how to use SAP Financials.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking out this note:

https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/2371425

Cause
The report RFIDYYWT uses the logical database KDF or DDF to get all the details , which was optimized for SAP HANA with SAP Note 2250725 and 2254757.

Resolution
Implement the following notes :

2327597 - KDF: No withholding tax lines
2311156 - FBL5N - vendor documents are ignored
2315607 - KDF: Dump after ASSERT
2301994 - DDF - documents are ignored